# Another Look at GIS StackExchange - Analysis

Tags: discussion, blog, stack-exchange

What do users think of the Tag Analysis of the following?

A **2013** update to last years “Carving Up GIS StackExchange” now  “Another Look at GIS StackExchange” by Bill Dollins

http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/another-look-at-gis-stackexchange/

*(Yes the GIS Stack Exchange Blog still exists - if you want to create your own GIS-StackExchange Blog Post please contact mapperz)*

Comment: This is not a question. Perhaps you should post it in the chat section.

Comment: not many use the chat room - if the messaging system was still available would of use that (as previously have) but it is related to our site.

Comment: I am sympathetic, but that does not seem to be sufficient reason to ignore [site guidelines](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: added to the chat, can revamp to ask a question.

Answer (score 6):

I am curious about the opening statement:

> Compared to last year’s results, there hasn’t been much movement in the distribution of tags.

This raises many questions, including

- How are you measuring the distribution?
- What exactly do you mean by "movement"?
- How much movement would be significant or of interest?
- Why should we care--what does the tag distribution say about our
  site?

**We should be cautious about drawing *any* inferences from these data.**  After all, one obvious reason the `qgis` tag has become more popular is that the [official QGIS website](http://www.qgis.org/en/community.html) now lists us as their main help resource.  (A year and half ago [it did not](http://web.archive.org/web/20120317213017/http://www.qgis.org/en/community.html).) Thus we cannot draw any (supported) conclusions about the relative popularity or usage or tendency to create problems of this software, nor can we really draw any conclusions about possible changes in our active user community.

Comment: I note that all 3 of the top "vendor" tags named in Dollins' report -- `arcgis`, `opengeo`, `qgis` -- have prominent links to GIS.se on their official support websites.

Comment: @matt I searched the ESRI site for "stack exchange" and "stackexchange" and found nothing. Using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aesri.com+stackexchange) I turned up some stuff--but most of it was from my signature (and Kirk Kuykendall's signature) on their forums! Where do you find this prominent link?

Comment: Not sure about the link, but within the past month, I've worked through a couple of python Esri support issues where they've actually provided gis.stackexchange.com links (which didn't turn out to be helpful).

Comment: Thanks @Jay, that's good to know. There's quite a difference, though, between a support person providing a link in response to a question and a prominent link on the vendor's support page saying "go to GIS.SE for help!"

Comment: @mattwilkie The brand new (that is, approx. 2 months old) [ArcGIS for Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/support/) site _does_ include a link, but simply saying that both sites link to gis.stackexchange and it's therefore fair discounts the fact that the ArcGIS site's link is much younger and Esri has official support forums where many questions remain today, as opposed to QGIS.

Comment: @JasonScheirer, thanks for the clarification. It was the developers site I was thinking of when I commented, but in my mind I wasn't holding it as a distinct (or new) site from the other Esri properties.